# what are the pro's and con's of using table of from clause into select statement of where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query which is taking 40 sec to execute :

```
    select ID , OPERATOR_NAME, 
JOBS_BULK = ISNULL((select COUNT(distinct REPL_RUN) from Locationn r (NOLOCK) , Batch b (NOLOCK) 
                    where r.FROM_PRO_CODE = b.PRO_CODE and r.FROM_BAT_NUMBER = b.BAT_NUMBER and b.BAT_QUANTITY > 0 and r.ASSIGNED_BULK = o.OPERATOR_NAME and isnull(r.ASSIGNED_BULK_COMPLETE,'N')  = 'N'),0) , 
ITEMS_BULK = ISNULL((select COUNT(*) from Locationn r (NOLOCK) , Batch b (NOLOCK) 
                    where r.FROM_PRO_CODE = b.PRO_CODE and r.FROM_BAT_NUMBER = b.BAT_NUMBER and b.BAT_QUANTITY > 0 and  r.ASSIGNED_BULK = o.OPERATOR_NAME and isnull(r.ASSIGNED_BULK_COMPLETE,'N')  = 'N'),0) , 
JOBS_PICK = ISNULL((select COUNT(distinct REPL_RUN) from Locationn r (NOLOCK) , Batch b (NOLOCK) 
                    where r.FROM_PRO_CODE = b.PRO_CODE and r.FROM_BAT_NUMBER = b.BAT_NUMBER and b.BAT_QUANTITY > 0 and r.ASSIGNED_PICK = o.OPERATOR_NAME and isnull(r.ASSIGNED_PICK_COMPLETE,'N')  = 'N') ,0) ,
ITEMS_PICK = ISNULL((select COUNT(*) from Locationn r (NOLOCK) , Batch b (NOLOCK) 
                    where r.FROM_PRO_CODE = b.PRO_CODE and r.FROM_BAT_NUMBER = b.BAT_NUMBER and b.BAT_QUANTITY > 0 and r.ASSIGNED_PICK = o.OPERATOR_NAME and isnull(r.ASSIGNED_PICK_COMPLETE,'N')  = 'N') ,0) 
from Operatorr o
where  
(ISNULL((select COUNT(*) from Locationn r (NOLOCK) , Batch b (NOLOCK) 
        where ISNULL(ASSIGNED_BULK,' ') <> ' ' and r.FROM_PRO_CODE = b.PRO_CODE and r.FROM_BAT_NUMBER = b.BAT_NUMBER and b.BAT_QUANTITY > 0 and r.ASSIGNED_BULK = o.OPERATOR_NAME and isnull(r.ASSIGNED_BULK_COMPLETE,'N')  = 'N'),0) 
+ ISNULL((select COUNT(*) from Locationn r (NOLOCK) , Batch b (NOLOCK) 
        where ISNULL(ASSIGNED_PICK,' ') <> ' ' and r.FROM_PRO_CODE = b.PRO_CODE and r.FROM_BAT_NUMBER = b.BAT_NUMBER and b.BAT_QUANTITY > 0 and r.ASSIGNED_PICK = o.OPERATOR_NAME and isnull(r.ASSIGNED_PICK_COMPLETE,'N')  = 'N') ,0) ) <> 0
```

In the above query condition tblb.col1=oc.col1 was taking much time then expected.

So i optimized this query as below, it is taking only 4 sec to execute and giving the exact result:

```
    select ID , OPERATOR_NAME, 
JOBS_BULK = ISNULL((select COUNT(distinct REPL_RUN) from Locationn r (NOLOCK) , Batch b (NOLOCK) 
                    where r.FROM_PRO_CODE = b.PRO_CODE and r.FROM_BAT_NUMBER = b.BAT_NUMBER and b.BAT_QUANTITY > 0 and r.ASSIGNED_BULK = o.OPERATOR_NAME and isnull(r.ASSIGNED_BULK_COMPLETE,'N')  = 'N'),0) , 
ITEMS_BULK = ISNULL((select COUNT(*) from Locationn r (NOLOCK) , Batch b (NOLOCK) 
                    where r.FROM_PRO_CODE = b.PRO_CODE and r.FROM_BAT_NUMBER = b.BAT_NUMBER and b.BAT_QUANTITY > 0 and  r.ASSIGNED_BULK = o.OPERATOR_NAME and isnull(r.ASSIGNED_BULK_COMPLETE,'N')  = 'N'),0) , 
JOBS_PICK = ISNULL((select COUNT(distinct REPL_RUN) from Locationn r (NOLOCK) , Batch b (NOLOCK) 
                    where r.FROM_PRO_CODE = b.PRO_CODE and r.FROM_BAT_NUMBER = b.BAT_NUMBER and b.BAT_QUANTITY > 0 and r.ASSIGNED_PICK = o.OPERATOR_NAME and isnull(r.ASSIGNED_PICK_COMPLETE,'N')  = 'N') ,0) ,
ITEMS_PICK = ISNULL((select COUNT(*) from Locationn r (NOLOCK) , Batch b (NOLOCK) 
                    where r.FROM_PRO_CODE = b.PRO_CODE and r.FROM_BAT_NUMBER = b.BAT_NUMBER and b.BAT_QUANTITY > 0 and r.ASSIGNED_PICK = o.OPERATOR_NAME and isnull(r.ASSIGNED_PICK_COMPLETE,'N')  = 'N') ,0) 
from Operatorr o
where  
(ISNULL((select COUNT(*) from Locationn r (NOLOCK) , Batch b ,Operatorr c  (NOLOCK) 
        where ISNULL(ASSIGNED_BULK,' ') <> ' ' and r.FROM_PRO_CODE = b.PRO_CODE and r.FROM_BAT_NUMBER = b.BAT_NUMBER and b.BAT_QUANTITY > 0 and r.ASSIGNED_BULK =c.OPERATOR_NAME and c.OPERATOR_NAME =o.OPERATOR_NAME  and isnull(r.ASSIGNED_BULK_COMPLETE,'N')  = 'N'),0)
+ ISNULL((select COUNT(*) from Locationn r (NOLOCK) , Batch b ,Operatorr c (NOLOCK)  where ISNULL(ASSIGNED_PICK,' ') <> ' ' and r.FROM_PRO_CODE = b.PRO_CODE and r.FROM_BAT_NUMBER = b.BAT_NUMBER and b.BAT_QUANTITY > 0 and r.ASSIGNED_PICK = c.OPERATOR_NAME and c.OPERATOR_NAME =o.OPERATOR_NAME and isnull(r.ASSIGNED_PICK_COMPLETE,'N')  = 'N') ,0) )
<> 0
```

i just used a join of table tblA in the select statement of where clause.
Could you please tell me what is the technical reason, why 2nd query is taking less time to execute?

Comment: in 1st query table tblA have an alias name oc

Comment: Can you compare the execution plans in management studio?

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. Firstly, when writting SQL please don't be afraid to use WhiteSpace, it makes your SQL far more readable. Next, that can't be the SQL you used, it's not valid. The syntax `ISNULL({Subquery},{NULL Replacement})` is invalid. The Sub query needs to be wrapped in further parenthesis :`ISNULL(({Subquery}),{NULL replacement})`. Next, let's get you into 2018, you're using implicit `JOIN` syntax from the 80's there: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).

Comment: Finally, that query is far from SARGable. Using functions like `ISNULL` around a column, subquery, etc, ruins any chance of the optimiser using an index. I'll see what i can do to improve this, but the query needs to take a very different form.

Comment: That query makes my eyes bleed and my heart cry. It is so horrific to read because it just looks random characters thrown everywhere. Formatting is your your friend. My heart bleeds because NOLOCK is littered everywhere in that. Are you ok with randomly getting duplicate and/or missing rows? https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Answer (score 1):

This is very much a stab in the dark. After starting the changes I noticed more problems with your query. I've made a couple of comments, so note that and the items in the braces (`{}`). In the end, I couldn't see why you needed 2 sub queries; as you seem to be checking the same thing in your second query, and in the first just a different value for `tblb.{Some Column}` (`'xyz'` and `'abc'`).

Considering you just want to check if there are rows, there's no need for a `COUNT` either, you can use `EXISTS`. Finally, I've got rid of that 1980's implicit `JOIN` syntax.

If this doesn't give you the result you want, sample data and expected results are going to be key, and the actual SQL you used (as what you have provided won't work due to the syntax errors).

```
SELECT *
FROM tblA A
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM tblb B
                   JOIN tblc C ON B.Col1 = C.Col1
              WHERE B.{Some Column} IN ('xyz','abc')--The column name is missing in your original query
                                                    --Also in first query you had 'xyz' and 'abc' but 'xyz' both times in your second, which is it?
                AND B.col1 = A.col1);
```

Comment: thank for your suggestions, i have given an example of the my query.

Comment: @Ankush yes, but that example isn't valid T-SQL for the reasons in my answer/comments on your question; hence my note about needing the actual SQL. To reiterate,. however, the syntax `ISNULL({Subquery},{NULL Replacement})` will generate as error. Try `SELECT ISNULL(SELECT 1, 2);` for example, you'll get an error. The correct syntax is: `SELECT ISNULL((SELECT 1),2);`.

Comment: Yes i got it, i have edited my query in my question.

Comment: That query @Ankush is **very** different to what you originally supplied. I suggest looking at mine and Gordan's examples and working from those. There's no formatting to those queries, so they almost unreadable. There's a load of (possible misuse)`NOLOCK` in there as well. i suggest looking at this too: [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/)

Comment: Also, @Ankush I suggest against all those subqueries in the `SELECT`. They're going to really slow it down too. I recommend looking into`JOIN` syntax (possibly `LEFT JOIN`) aggregate functions and `GROUP BY` and `CASE` expressions. *Oh, and maybe `HAVING` too, and I doubt yoiu'll need that `EXISTS` anymore is you use `HAVING`.*

Comment: yeah that's right, putting NOLOCK  everywhere is not a good idea, but for now i have to put it  because at this time there are lots of process is in execution and i don't want to fail any of them.

Comment: Thank you so much for your  advice, i will try to optimise the query by keeping your advise in mind

Comment: Yes, but if you get rid of all those nasty sub queries then it's likely you won't have a locking issue. `NOLOCK` often isn't the solution to stopping other queries from failing when you have a slow running query. The solution is the fix the slow running query, not bloat it up with `NOLOCK` everywhere. Have a go at using everything I've mentioned above; your query will probably be considerably smaller (maybe no more than 10 lines with good whitespace/line break usage). if you get stuck, update your question again with your latest attempt and comment mentioning me and I'll help further.

Comment: *(I say with good whitespace/line break usage, as your query is probably closer to 60 lines or so with good usage, not the 15 it is.)*

Answer (score 1):

You should write such queries using `exists`.  I would start with:

```
select a.*
from tblA a
where exists (select 1
              from tblb b join
                   tblc c
                   on b.col1 = c.col1
              where b.? = 'xyz' and  -- unclear what column this is
                    b.col1 = a.col1
             ) and
       exists (select count (*)
               from tblb b join
                    tblc c
                    on b.col1 = c.col1
               where b.? = 'ABC' and
                     b.col1 = a.col1
              );
```

The difference that affects performance is using `exists`.  The following are best practices:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.
- Use qualified column names.
- Give tables aliases.

As for why your versions have different performance.  One possibility is caching.  Another is to study the execution plan.  The first would normally be better, but "normally" is not "always".